# Scrapy with Pycharm "ImportError: No module named settings"

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get passed this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kdawod/.virtualenvs/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 168, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/Users/kdawod/.virtualenvs/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 109, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 68, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 292, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named settings
```

It's only happening while running in PyCharm, however, it was working just fine the previous day.

I would be glad if you can help me figure out this issue and prevent it from happening in the future.

Comment: are you using some virtual environment outside pycharm? also what's the root folder selected on pycharm?

Comment: @eLRuLL yes I'm using virtualenvwrapper outside of PyCharm. i'm not sure what you mean by root folder. is it the project root or something else?

Comment: ok, so you need to specify that into Pycharm too, go to Preferences->Project Interpreter and then `Add Local` to search for the path of the python you want to use (the one inside the virtualwrapper folder).

Comment: Thanks @eLRuLL. I've added my python 2.7 virtualenv. also, when I unchecked `Add content roots to PYTHONPATH` it seemed to work just fine. that's must've been the problem.

Comment: nice, hope I helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because Pycharm isn't finding the correct `scrapy` installation because it is trying to use the system's python version.

As you are using `virtualenvwrapper` outside Pycharm, you also need to define that inside. You have to specify the path of the python installation inside your virtual environment.

To select it in Pycharm go to:

```
Preferences -> Project: myproject -> Project Interpreter
```

and then select `Add Local` on the gear close to the upper-right corner which will help you browse where the correct python installation could be.